# Error when using crispy forms with Django and bootstrap

Tags: python, html, django, django-crispy-forms

I have created a sign in page for my blog, using bootstrap and django. I recently imported crispy forms and when I try and go to the page I get the following error: `TemplateDoesNotExist at /register/`. However all my redirects and URLs are setup correctly.

On the Django debug it says that the error is in my base HTML file, under the head section where I imported bootstrap CSS. I can provide any code necessary. It says this on my server: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: bootsrap4.4.1/uni_form.html`.

Comment: Do you have some `{% include %}` statement in your base.html?

Comment: Are you using the django-bootstrap package by any chance?

Comment: Did you set your setting `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK` correctly? it should be something like `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'`. Looks like you have it currently set to the full version number.

Answer (score 4):

install this version of django-crispy-forms "django-crispy-forms==1.14.0" and your problems will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue and then realized that it depends on what Bootstrap version you've either installed or which version CDN you're referring to in your template. I used 'bootstrap4' as the CRISPY-TEMPLATE_PACK in my settings.py, but in my base.html template, i'm using Bootstrap5 CDN, therefore Django is not able to retrieve bootstrap4/uni_form.html.

So make sure your template is using the same version of Bootstrap as the one you put in your settings.py.

Comment: How do I make sure what version of Bootstrap am I using in the template?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding django-crispy-forms templates packs are now in separate package,

depending on the boostrap version you are using, You will need to `pip install crispy-bootstrap4`  and add `crispy_bootstrap4` to your list of INSTALLED_APPS.
That will solve your issue